# Определение языка nsstring

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Каким образом можно определить язык строки в NSString?
Пробую следующим образом:

```
NSString *text = @"text";
NSString *lang = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFStringTokenizerCopyBestStringLanguage( (CFStringRef)text, CFRangeMake(0, text.length) ));
```

Каждый раз выдает `null`

Также пробовал [эту](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6325560) функцию.

Comment: а почему не этот пример? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13783833

Comment: Да, действительно такой метод работает. Но язык конечно не совсем корректно определяет)

Answer (score 1):

примерный перевод [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325073/detect-language-of-nsstring/13783833#13783833):

В cocoa есть API для проверки языка строки.

```
NSArray *tagschemes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage, nil];
NSLinguisticTagger *tagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:tagschemes options:0];
[tagger setString:@"Das ist ein bisschen deutscher Text. Bitte löschen Sie diesen nicht."];
NSString *language = [tagger tagAtIndex:0 scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage tokenRange:NULL sentenceRange:NULL];
```

Другой подход, если у вас несколько языков в тексте, вы можете использовать enumerateLinguisticTagsInRange чтобы получить язык отдельного слова в тексте.